# magento 2 hide shipping methods for specific state

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want to hide fedex and usps shipping methods for some states. I am trying to get the selected state in the **getShippingMethods** functions which returns the avaialable shipping methods. This function is in **ShippingMethodManagement** class.

I tried getting region id by **$shippingAddress->getRegionId()** but it just returns the default shipping address state, not the selected one.

I also tried getting the region id using checkout session but same result.

If anyone have the solution for this, please share.

thanks

Comment: Related question: I want to hide free shipping for specific state like Alaska, Hawaii etc.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159494)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else get into the same issue. I was getting shipping address from quote and the session, which was returning me default address.

Today i checked the function again **private function getShippingMethods(Quote $quote, $address)** and the answer was in its 2nd parameter.

**$address->getRegionId()** contains the selected state id.